# Subversion shows two different repositories at the same URL

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I went to checkout an old project and found that it contained no files. I went to my original computer, opened the windows folder that contains the working copy of the project and, using TortoiseSVN opened the repository browser. It showed the original project with all of the source revisions intact. In fact, it shows a different folder structure. If I go to a different project on the same computer and open the repository browser I see the same repository as I saw on my new PC. I apparently have two repositories with the same URL.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if:
1) you connect from both location to the same repo (by it's IP)
2) you connect under the credentials of the same SVN-user

Most probably, you used different logins and can see Path-Based ACL in action